# Reconfigurable antennas at base-station

Tags: antenna, mobile

Can reconfigurable antennas be used at base-stations and cellphone towers? I read that MIMO antennas are used at base-stations for 4G systems (and will be used for 5G). Are these antennas reconfigurable?

Comment: An antenna has no idea what form the signal is that is fed to it and anyone reading this question has no idea what antennas you specifically refer to.

Comment: I'm referring to patch array antennas.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by “reconfigurable antenna”, but a MIMO system has multiple antennas at the transmitter TX and also multiple antennas at the receiver RX.

This can be used to kind of “form” the radiation pattern of the TX or to improve the data reception of the RX through spatial diversity.

In short: Multiple antennas provide better communication channels. (But this does not scale endlessly with number of antennas.)